# ViewPager/PageAdapter problems with importing resources

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Alright, so I downloaded the android support package and installed v4,
but for some reason none of the Activities I need can be imported.  This is the first time I have tried using the support package and I have only been programming android for 4 weeks so sorry if the answer is obvious.[image]

Comment: From where you are adding android-supported-v4.jar file.

Answer (score 1):

> Right click on your project
>
> Choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path  -> Select Java Build Path
>   -> Go to Libraries -> Click on Add External Jars.. -> Then Choose android-support-v4.jar -> Then Press on OK.
>
> Where to find android-support-v4.jar file.
>
> Got to the android installation folder
>
> android-Sdk -> extras -> android -> support -> v4 -> (In that you'll
>   find) android-support-v4.jar.

Comment: Either that, or you can simply right click on the new .jar (in eclipse, just where it is in your screenshot) and than 'build path' -> 'add to build path'.